# Where should I put this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

I need to update multiple instances of a model for a transaction. Should I make a class method and updates all the instances in the method or should I move that logic to the controller and updates each instance via an instance method for the model? I guess it is a tradeoff between fat controller vs. fat model and the general advice is fat model over fat controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. If it's a significant piece of logic, why not incorporate it into a dedicated class?

Alternatively, if your (I'm assuming) form data can be configured thus:

```
params[:models] = { id_of_instance_1 => { :attribute => value }, 
                    id_of_instance_2 => { :attribute => value2 },
                  }
```

You can quite easily do a group update in your controller with:

```
Model.update(params[:models].keys, params[:models].values)
```

More information about the details you're updating and where they're coming from could help.

---

EDIT: After reading your response below...

There's a few ways you could do it. You could implement `Model.win` and `Model.lose` as class methods to incorporate the logic, then simply call those methods from your controller:

```
def process_outcome
  @winner = Model.win(params[:winning_id])
  @loser = Model.lose(params[:losing_id])
end
```

Or, even as a single method call:

```
def process_outcome
  # passing the entire params hash to `process_outcome` which returns an array
  @winner, @loser = Model.process_outcome(params)
end
```

Personally, if the only child objects involved are all instances of the same model, I'd implement this logic within the class itself.

However, if you're bringing a variety of classes into the mix, it might be worth encapsulating it into a separate object altogether:

```
# app/controllers/models_controller.rb
def process_outcome
  @outcome_processor = OutcomeProcessor.new(params)
  @winner = @outcome_processor.winner
  @loser  = @outcome_processor.loser
end
```

Either way, your actual transaction block should *not* be in the Controller.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a straight through update as you suggested but having a dedicated class might make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. What I have done is a single class method call as you suggested though it's worth considering encapsulating it into a separate object together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the tradition. :)
You can use a different class (Not controllers) to write transaction method.

Comment: Tradition as in fat model? I wonder if there is anything wrong with creating a class method in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It should almost certainly go in the model, not the controller.

I think it should go in an instance method, not a class method. My reasoning behind this is that you're likely going to be calling this via the URL `/model/id/action?other_model_id=other_id`. Then it would follow that in the controller action you'd get appropriate model instance for `id`, as well as `other_id`, but since this is the path for the `id` model, not the `other_id` model, you'd call `@id_model.perform_action(@other_id_model)`.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Actually my needs are a bit more complicated. The call is a REST JSON call passing in 2 user ids (winner and loser) as you indicated. For each of the user, I need to update several instances (more than 2) of a child model instances and that's where I'm using the class method. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hmmmm. Well you should do your best to keep it out of the controller. The controller should only do the minimum needed to pass data between the model and view/request. Remember: [thin controllers, fat models](http://www.mikebernat.com/images/cake/layercake.png).